# Matrix multiply a Vector using Loc/Rot/Scale Attributes

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, matrix

I am making a setup that uses Object Coordinates from an Empty as Normals. This works great until you start moving the object with a rig, at which point you realize that these "Normals" are in the wrong space, even if the Empty is constrained to move with the deformations. Any shading they produce will look like its stuck to the mesh. The solution is to get the Empty's Matrix, and multiply the Object Coordinate vector by them.

Here's a setup I made awhile back, before the Attribute node, that does that (but I don't fully understand it):
[image]
This does work, but its a mess, and requires manually creating a driver for each value in the Matrix. I am now trying to make a better version that uses Attributes to bring in the Loc/Rot/Scale of an object, and then does the operation with Vector Math. But I do not really understand the relation between Loc/Rot/Scale and the 16 values that go into a Matrix.

I have the Loc/Rot/Scale as custom properties on my mesh object:
[image]

And I have the attribute nodes bringing them in, and the Object Vector:
[image]

But now what?
Is Loc/Rot/Scale the wrong things to be using? I believe it contains the same information as the Matrix Values, but I don't really understand how they relate to each other. For example, if you rotate the object, several of the values are changing, including ones that I know are Scale.
[image]

I can bring the full Matrix in through custom props + attributes instead I suppose, but I'd like a cleaner solution if possible. (Its also easier to setup Loc/Rot/Scale as there are addons to quickly create those props.)